# How can I implement semicircle-shaped buttons in iPhone applications

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton

I got a iPhone app design made in Photoshop. I converted the PSD file to PNG format.

I found it difficult to implement, especially on some portions like semicircle-shaped buttons.

How can I implement this semicircle-shape as two buttons?

[image]

Comment: "But on implementation I found it hard especially on some portions like semi-circle shaped button." That sentence does not make any sense to me. Please clarify.

Comment: Hey @nithin, welcome to StackOverflow. Unfortunately, your question is overly broad and it will probably be closed shortly. I suggest that you take a look at the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) and then try posting a specific question.

Comment: I need to use a semi-circle as two buttons.

Comment: @nithin Could you upload an image of the buttons you’re trying to implement?

Comment: @Moshe The question looks specific enough for me.

Comment: @Bavarious - the question as originally worded was nowhere near this specific.

Comment: @sosborn I agree that the _title_ wasn’t but the question body was IMO. In such cases, it’s a matter of improving the title. Voting to close was premature IMO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Draw two quarter circle images in Photoshop, saved at PNG files. In your nib file make two custom buttons the size of the quarter circles, each with one of these quarter circle images. Place the two buttons next to each other. You can embellish the buttons by drawing the various states of the button as separate PNG files, and add those images to the nib file definition of the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following link. It works amazingly

Visit http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.in/2010/03/irregularly-shaped-uibuttons.html